# Display two or more displaymembers in binded listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

After joining two tables, i want to display the name and the first_name of user:

```
string name_p = list_profiles.Text;
int id_profile;
var profile = SundicappEntities.Instance.users_profiles.First(u => u.name_p== name_p);
id_profile = profile.id_profile;

var q = 
     from user in SundicappEntities.Instance.users
     join map in SundicappEntities.Instance.user_profile_map on user.id_user equals map.id_user 
     where map.id_profile==id_profile
     select new
     {
         user.name_user,
         user.f_name_user               
     };

usersBindingSource1.DataSource = q.ToList();
listBox_map.DataSource = usersBindingSource1;
listBox_map.DisplayMember = "name_user"+" " + "f_name_user";
```

It returns the correct data, but it display it like this:

> {name_user=xxxx.f_name_user=yyyy}

My problem is how to display many displaymembers in listbox!
Thank you to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom property in your class object that returns you the correct string.

```
public string ListBoxItemDisplayText
{
    get
    {
         return name_user + " " + f_name_user ;
    }
}
```

You can create this property in the linq new construct as well

```
select new
      {
         ListBoxItemDisplayText = user.name_user + " " + user.f_name_user     
      };
```

Bind this property to the `DisplayMember` property.

`listBox_map.DisplayMember = "ListBoxItemDisplayText";`